# How to get MIME encoded base64 string back to writeable byte array?

Tags: c#, encoding, base64

I have a number of files (PDF, doc, docx, jpg, etc) in a database, which were added using the following method:

> Attachments are sent to the database as MIME-encoded (base64-encoded)
>   strings. The component then converts this MIME-encoded string (in
>   unicode) to a byte stream before writing it to the database as a BLOB
>   (Oracle) or Image (SQL Server).

There is also a 'guid' appended to the start of the string, which is 76 chars.

I'm trying to extract and save the attachments to a file on disk rather than in the database. It works about 20% of the time. The remainder of the time I get `System.FormatException: Invalid character in a Base-64 string.` when passing my string into `FromBase64String`.

I have noticed that values in the database that start like the below, save successfully:

`0x7B00350030003100460032003300350046002D00370`

The ones which fail always start like this:

`0x7B35303146323335462D373546302D343936342D394`

I haven't got enough characters here to paste a full example, so see [this pastebin](https://pastebin.com/ESveG4Rx) for an example of one that does not work. It should represent a Word document that says "Test document only". [This one](https://pastebin.com/xmrxEYNE) is the same document but converted to PDF.

[This](https://pastebin.com/yraWz7Te) is one that will work and be converted to `test font.htm`. It must be inserted into an `image` column within a SQL database, then pulled out with my code:

```
 private const int guidLength = 38 * 2;
 public static byte[] GetAttachment(string folderid, string filename) {
 string queryString = string.Format("SELECT <image column> FROM AttachmentTable WHERE .....",
                      folderid, filename);
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("context connection=true"))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand selectAttachment = new SqlCommand(
                        queryString,
                        connection))
                    {
                        using (SqlDataReader reader = selectAttachment.ExecuteReader())                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                if (reader[0] == System.DBNull.Value)
                                    return new byte[0];
                                byte[] data = (byte[])reader[0];
                                byte[] truncatedData;
                                if (data[data.Length - 2] == 0)
                                    truncatedData = new byte[data.Length - guidLength - 2];
                                else
                                    truncatedData = new byte[data.Length - guidLength];
                                Array.Copy(data, guidLength, truncatedData, 0, truncatedData.Length);
                                // base64 unencode
                                string truncatedString = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(truncatedData);
                                return Convert.FromBase64String(truncatedString);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                } 

             }
```

Then to save the attachment:

```
 public static void SaveAttachmentToFile(string file, string folderid, string fileName)
        {
            byte[] data = GetAttachment(file, folderid);
            if (data == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Attachment has no data, it may have been deleted");
            using (FileStream writer = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
            {
                writer.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }
        }
```

SQL CLR Function

```
   [SqlFunction(IsDeterministic = true,
                     IsPrecise = true,
                     DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read,
                     SystemDataAccess = SystemDataAccessKind.Read)]
    public static SqlString WriteToFile(SqlString path, SqlString folderid, SqlString fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!path.IsNull && !folderid.IsNull && !fileName.IsNull)
            {
                var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(path.Value);
                if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
                string filename = Convert.ToString(fileName);
                string folderid = Convert.ToString(efolderid);
                string filepath = Convert.ToString(path);
                SaveAttachmentToFile(filename, folderid, filepath);
                return "Wrote file";
            }
            else
                return "No data passed to method!";
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            return "Make sure the assembly has external access!\n" + e.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Note, All the C# code above is compiled into an assembly then used as a CLR function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[WriteToFile](@path [nvarchar](max), @efolderid [nvarchar](max), @filename [nvarchar](max))
RETURNS [nvarchar](max) WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
EXTERNAL NAME [ClassLibrary1].[CLR.UserDefinedFunctions].[WriteToFile]
GO
```

I think my issue might be to do with the encoding. I thought I might be able to use `Encoding.MIME.GetString` but it doesn't exist. I've also tried `UTF-8` but get 0% success rate. Unicode seems to work but as above, ~20% success rate.

My question is, why do some of these fail to save (incorrect base64 chars.. but why?) yet others work fine? How do I determine the correct encoding to use? There is a pattern to it but I'm really not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: Those don't look like base64 strings to me. They look like a sequence of bytes represented by hexadecimal pairs.

Comment: Perhaps, but some of them do translate to base64 and then I can save the files to disk

Comment: That doesn't mean you end up with any kind of valid data. Try just cutting off the 0x at the start, then iterate over them per two and convert them to byte value from hex string, and save the resulting byte array.

Comment: @Nyerguds Nope - not really sure how to approach that. Do you have a rough idea of how to implement the `byte value from hex string` part, like, is it a built in .net function or something i need to write myself?

Comment: Apologies. further study of your data seem to make it into an encoding problem. The data you say _works_ has 00 bytes in between, making it most likely UTF-16 encoded strings. Your problem lies in the line `Encoding.Unicode.GetString` - this is UTF16. You will have to detect those 00 bytes, and in case they _don't_ appear, don't use `Encoding.Unicode` but `Encoding.ASCII` to convert it to string. It seems the input of the data is not as reliable as you were told.

Comment: It was somewhat unclear from your question that the "0x" format was just how the data was _shown_ by whatever you used to check the database, and not how you actually _got_ the data in your program. Though from careful reading of the code itself this could definitely be deduced, so I apologise for my rudeness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given data insertion method is ambiguous; "unicode" is not actually a text encoding; it is the general system of representing symbols as a number. The .Net framework indeed has an encoding called "Unicode", but this is a misnomer, this encoding is actually UTF-16.

Now, your data, as mentioned, comes in two formats; one that works, and one that doesn't work. The difference between those two formats is that one of them has `00` bytes in between each of the data bytes. This corresponds to UTF-16-LE, where all symbols are 16 bits, aka, 2 bytes, with the lowest part of the value stored in the first byte. The compact data without those `00` bytes should be plain ASCII.

This UTF-16 format is actually a pretty dumb way of saving Base64 data, since Base64, by definition, is *always* pure 7-bit ascii; these extra bytes will never be used, and just double the space required to save that data. In fact, when saved as bytes, there is no merit to Base64 encoding either, since the purpose of Base64 is to convert binary data to plain text so it can be handled by systems that can't handle storing/transferring binary data. Given the fact this Base64 text is then saved as Binary LOB in your database, this is clearly not the case here.

All that aside, the `00` bytes *do* give a solution for your problem here: as I said, for Base64 content, these in-between bytes will never be used, meaning they will *always* be `00`. On the other hand, Base64 is always plain ASCII text and should *never* contain 00 bytes. This means you can check those `00` bytes and use their existence to choose the correct encoding.

Note that it is much simpler to cut off the GUID *after* converting the bytes to string, since then it will simply always have a length of 38, as opposed to being either 38 bytes in ASCII or 76 bytes in UTF-16.

Adapting the reader part of your first code block to this should solve the issue:

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = selectAttachment.ExecuteReader())
{
    // only reading one anyway; doesn't need to be a 'while'.
    if (!reader.Read())
        return new byte[0];
    if (reader[0] == System.DBNull.Value)
        return new byte[0];
    byte[] data = (byte[])reader[0];
    if (data.Length == 0)
        return new byte[0];
    String base64String
    if (data.Length > 1 && data[1] == 00)
        base64String = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data);
    else
        base64String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
    // Cuts off the GUID, and takes care of any trailing 00 bytes.
    String truncatedString = base64String.Substring(38).TrimEnd('\0');
    return Convert.FromBase64String(truncatedString);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this works perfectly and I appreciate the detailed explanation. I was mad yesterday because this had been frustrating me so much, apologies for the aggressive comment. I'd actually have never figured this out by myself so I owe you one. :)

Comment: Yeah, there was some confusion about that 0x stuff... I blindly followed the already-posted comment about that without actually thoroughly reading the code. Sorry about that.

Comment: All good. I appreciate the time taken to help out on this one.

Comment: I actually spotted the problem after dumping both of your hex samples in an online hex-to-text converter, and noticing that the resulting text (being the start of these guids) was identical for both, but for the working sample the converted string was a lot _shorter,_ despite the input being the same size. That's when I noticed the 00 bytes, which the converter had simply thrown out because they weren't valid letters.